# How to block access to a website if its directly accessed with it's IP address using a .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to know how to prevent visitors of my website to access it using the website's IP address. I want to do this through a .htaccess file. I just want it to say "Forbidden" when they try it. But if they visit the website using it's domain name they have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

If there is nothing in the host header, it returns forbidden. There would be an empty host header for access by IP.

A better way is to put a default `<VirtualHost>` in the config for that IP, so requests by IP never get served by the site. I guess this may not be an option for you since you requested a .htaccess solution. The above method blocks HTTP 1.0 clients but that's really not much of a concern these days.

Comment: What does an answerer have to do to get an upvote round here! :)